# Why is the string 'andy' not printing please enter a new username?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

```
current_users = ['Andy', 'Brett', 'Cassie', 'Derek', 'Eric']
new_users = ['eric', 'greg', 'hank', 'ian', 'john', 'andy', 'frank']
new_users.sort()

for current_user in current_users:
    current_user = current_user.lower()

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user == current_user:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Please enter a new username!")
    else:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Username is available.")
```

Andy is being printed as username is available.
Also please help me simplify as I am just learning python.

Comment: The line `if new_user == current_user:` only checks against `'eric'`, since that was the last assignment to `current_user` in the first loop. I think you meant to write `if new_user in current_users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **list comprehension** to convert the usernames in `current_users` to `lowercase`. Secondly, you've to check whether the `new_user` is already present in `current_users` to do that you have to use `in` keyword.

### The `in` keyword

> tests whether or not a sequence contains a certain value.

here is code,

```
current_users = ['Andy', 'Brett', 'Cassie', 'Derek', 'Eric']
new_users = ['eric', 'greg', 'hank', 'ian', 'john', 'andy', 'frank']
new_users.sort()

current_users = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Please enter a new username!")
    else:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Username is available.")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `in` to the list:

```
current_users = ['Andy', 'Brett', 'Cassie', 'Derek', 'Eric']
new_users = ['eric', 'greg', 'hank', 'ian', 'john', 'andy', 'frank']
new_users.sort()

current_users = [i.lower() for i in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Please enter a new username!")
    else:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Username is available.")
```

Answer (score -2):

a single equal mark is used to assign a value to a variable, whereas two consecutive equal marks is used to check whether 2 expressions give the same value .

= is an assignment operator

== is an equality operator

```
current_users = ['Andy', 'Brett', 'Cassie', 'Derek', 'Eric']
new_users = ['eric', 'greg', 'hank', 'ian', 'john', 'andy', 'frank']
new_users.sort()

for current_user in current_users:
    current_user == current_user.lower()

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user == current_user:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Please enter a new username!")
    else:
        print(f"\n{new_user}, Username is available.")
```